# Can SSH be used to encrypt communication between applications like SSL/TLS?

Tags: security, ssl, ssh

I saw a lot of questions and posts about the difference between SSL/TLS and SSH like

1. [Difference between SSH and SSL, especially in terms of “SFTP” vs. “FTP over SSL”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/723152/difference-between-ssh-and-ssl-especially-in-terms-of-sftp-vs-ftp-over-ssl)
2. [SSH vs SSL](http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-ssh-and-ssl/)
3. [What is the difference between SSL vs SSH? Which is more secure?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/what-is-the-difference-between-ssl-vs-ssh-which-is-more-secure)

I got the concept. They both provide encryption, but are not used for the same things. [This post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1599/what-is-the-difference-between-ssl-vs-ssh-which-is-more-secure) says, that this is mostly a historical decision. Currently I'm using TLS to secure the connections between my server and client applications (OpenSSL and Sockets). I'm just curious if it would be technically possible and reasonable to use SSH where SSL is used? Are there any drawbacks or obstacles?

Note: I know that SSH is also an application, which can be used to remote connect to another pc. But I'm not interested in the application, just the protocol.

Comment: Yes. Ansible is doing kind of this. As you mentioned SFTP, but there is rsync or others. You will need to have ssh server running on the target machine or run your own instance.

Comment: Is there any benefit of choosing SSH over SSL/TLS for this purpose? Because running an extra SSH server seems to be a overhead that is not needed while using SSL/TLS.

Comment: If you use SSH, you don't care in your application about certificates and host verification and. SSH takes care of it. Your application can just read/write to sockets, which will get forwarded to the opposite side if you have socket-oriented protocol, or just pipe the data through stdin/stdout of `ssh`.

Comment: Sounds quite handy. Why are not more applications using SSH than? Does TLS have a better performance or something?

Comment: with ssl you can use the system-wide certificates authorities, which is more suitable for end-users of browser or mail clients. There is no such world-wide or chainy-thing for SSH, even though you can use CA for your bunch of servers and eliminate the need of passwords, hostkey verification and so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use SSH for the same purpose.

Though as TLS (SSL) is more commonly used for the task, there are libraries to create an TLS-encrypted socket, both server- and client- side, which you use to implement your own protocol.

I'm not sure there are libraries to easily create SSH-encrypted sockets (without all the other SSH stuff, like authentication). I assume some SSH libraries can do that.

Though I do not think there's any advantage in using SSH over TLS. And for TLS you will find much more examples.

---

Reaction to [comment by @Jakuje](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34491681/850848#comment56726130_34491681):

With SSH, you still need to verify the host key, what is the equivalent to verifying the TLS certificate. While there's well established way to distribute, sign, revoke, etc... certificates, there's no equivalent for host keys in the standard SSH. The host key is like a self-signed certificate.

So you have to hard code the expected host key to your application. If you ever need to change the server-side private key (because you lose it or it gets compromised), the clients stop working.

Note that OpenSSH has proprietary support for hostkeys signed by certificates. That's more close to TLS, but OpenSSH certificates do not have certificate chain that  link your hostkey to a trusted root certificate built-in into your system (the way it's typical with TLS). So you have to approve the certificate manually, at least once.