# Microsoft.XMLHTTP using SSL client certificate (or an already authenticated session)

Tags: ssl, ssh, vbscript, xmlhttprequest, client-certificates

I am connecting to a server via a proxy that requires a client certificate to authenticate. I can easily launch a browser from my script, utilizing an ssh tunnel already established in a browser. When I attempt to open a connection using `Microsoft.XMLHTTP`, I receive an error

> Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid.

I am looking for one of two solutions:

1. utilize a session that is already (manually) established in a browser
2. send the client certificate (and PIN) via the script.

The logic that I'm currently using for this function is very simple:

```
Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
xHttp.Open "GET", "https://localhost:63619/ap_detail.xml?id=3502", False
xHttp.Send

With bStrm
    .Type = 1 '//binary
    .Open
    .Write xHttp.responseBody
    .SaveToFile "C:\xml\3502.xml", 2 '//overwrite
End With
```

Comment: [Maybe related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9971056/1630171).

Comment: Is this the issue you are having? ssh -p 63619 -o HostKeyAlias="remotemachine" localhost This will tell SSH to not check the "localhost" certificate, but rather that for "remotemachine".  http://spencerstirling.com/computergeek/sshtunnel.html

Comment: This page has a good description of how SSL and SSH differ in the certificate setup.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723152/difference-between-ssh-and-ssl-especially-in-terms-of-sftp-vs-ftp-over-ssl